# DataTables can't get json

Tags: javascript, html, json, express, datatables

I use nodejs express and I want to show user data in my datatables

javascript datables

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#dataTable').DataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": {
        "datatype": "json",
        "url": "/users",
        "dataSrc": ""
    },
        "columns":
            [
                { "data": "name" },
                { "data": "nickname" },
                { "data": "age" },
                { "data": "nicknames" }
            ]
})
})
```

json user data

```
{
name: "Apiphoom",
nickname: "Api",
age: "23",
test: "test"
}
```

html

```
          <table class="table table-bordered" id="dataTable"  >
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Nickname</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Test</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
          </table>
```

but it said "No matching records found",
How can I solve it.

Comment: Why is the URL just "/users" and not the full URL?

Comment: Can you add a snippet of your API output ? Also, Check if the API call actually resolves (console will tell), Check setting `"serverSide": false,` as I can recall, when `"serverSide": true,` it requires the endpoint to have certain parameters

Comment: my console don't  tell anything.

Comment: I try use Full URL but it also said "No matching records found"